# check statement error pdo

Tags: php, pdo, error-handling

i am using this construct for checking the error why a statement is not executed:

```
$value1 = $username;
$value2 = $firstname;
$value3 = $lastname;

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (row1, row2, row3) VALUES (?, ? , ?)";

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $value1);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value2);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $value3);

    $stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $var .= $e->getMessage();
}

include 'log.php';
```

log.php:

```
$logfile = fopen("logfile.txt", "a"); 
$error = date("d.m.Y H:i:s")." - ".$var.".\r\n"; 
fwrite($logfile, $error); 
fclose($logfile);
```

there is no insert in my database and my log.php is empty as well, so i cant save the error, anybody could help me? greetings

Comment: Can you show your $sql ?

Comment: where is the pdo contructor?

Comment: Could you post the whole code? That where $sql, $value1, $value2 and $value3 are defined

Comment: OK i edited the code :) could you refer to it=?

Comment: Did you enable exceptions in PDO? By default it runs silently and RETURNS errors instead of throwing exceptions.

Comment: thats all of the code i used..shall i add this setAttribute ?

Comment: [setAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php), in particular the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`

Comment: yea i did all of this, now i get this error in my logfile: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. anybody knows why?

Comment: @user3122124, the number of `?` placeholders must match the number of variables you bind to them. In the example code you show, the number is three in both cases, so that code should not generate an error. You must have different code that you aren't showing us.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why PDO errors attracts so distinct attention of PHP users. You would never see an include or an image manipulation so much nursed. But PDO statements, for some reason, always receive a special treatment.

While there is absolutely nothing special with PDO errors. That's exactly the same error as any other, and there is no need to treat PDO errors whatever special way. If a file was not found - PHP will log that error. If PDO query fails - **PHP will log that error** as well. Just tell PHP to do so.

```
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
```

is all you need. Then run your code and have an error logged

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (row1, row2, row3) VALUES (?, ? , ?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($username, $firstname, $lastname));
```